# Why does the agent not go to the right attractor?

Tags: anylogic

i have a fork-lifter who takes the item from the truck and stock it in the rectangular node.
The problem is that i want that the fork-lifter stock the agent according to the attractors. Instead, the operator goes in the same point every time. Why?(i did the same with another flowchart and same blocks and there is no problem, maybe a network problem?).[image: image1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu have to manually tell it to which attractor it should go. Attractors are not actual physical spaces (that become "full" if something is stored there). They are just spaces to separate things visually.

In your process blocks, you probably did not specify the attractors correctly or did not define to move to a random attractor. But even in the latter case, you could have things being stored in the same attractor.

Two options:

1. Either, turn your attractors into actual agents with rectangular nodes, that you setup to be "empty/full" with state charts (faster but harder to design)
2. Or use the material handling library with its storage system setup, doing this for your (but this is computationally slower)

Comment: thanks. I used a collection of attractor and a moveto with attractor as destination, using a collection.get(index).

Comment: and you are sure the index is different each time? Traceln the index used for each operation and make sure the respective attractors are actually spaced apart.

Comment: yes, because the index is a variable that increments of 1 on enter of the agent

Comment: it is not practical but it's just for a presentation.

Comment: add more details to the question. Could well be a network problem, hard to say. Some tips to edit your original question: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow